# Help in selecting proper Stack Exchange forum for discussion on a November 2021 Stanford article

Tags: discussion

I was wondering what forum I may find participants here at Stack Exchange that are open to discussing the foundations offered in this article in November 2021:

[Researchers propose a simpler design for quantum computers.](https://phys.org/news/2021-11-simpler-quantum.html?fbclid=IwAR1Mhr_Yta_mBh1J9pRM_kT9aGbTBt8Qrt3nD1R_WKdqdybVSisTMqLweo0)

Thank you very much.

Sincerely,

Justin

P.S. Basic sciences associated with topic:

Quantum Computing. Quantum Mechanics. Data Science. Physics. Mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a specific question about that topic, you can ask it on the main site. Just be mindful that StackExchange sites are generally not well-suited for open-ended or opinion-based discussions. You might try asking in the chat if you are looking for this sort of discussion. There's also physics forums around, e.g. https://www.physicsforums.com, but I don't have much experience with them so I wouldn't know what to suggest.

Comment: Why did you migrate this question, effectively banning it from your StackExchange subforum? "You must have at least 5 reputation on Quantum Computing Stack Exchange to answer a question on meta."

Comment: @JayPeek because this sort of question is off-topic on the main site, sorry. Question about how/what can/shoult be asked on the main site are to be asked on meta (*i.e.* here). I thought it preferable to migrate here rather than just outright closing it, as you can get answers here (I also feel compelled to point out that [StackExchange is *not* a forum in the sense some might be used to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/276202)). See also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic